# Domain Ownership Criteria (.eu)

Tags: dns, registration, nominet

Depending on the outcome of discussions political in the UK, we may lose the right to hold .eu domains on the 29th of the month. This is mandated by EurID who hold authority over the .eu domain.

https://eurid.eu/en/register-a-eu-domain/brexit-notice/

The only viable ways to work around this are to transfer the ownership of the domain to a European registered location, or lose the domain. EurID have already stated they plan to offer a very limited period of flexibility, but after the 29th of March they will be looking to lock down any changes to the domains from UK locations.

My question is what constitutes a change in domain ownership? I have a friend in Germany who is quite happy to hold the domain for me for a year or so to offer a migration period. I have been told by Ionos that changing the Reg-C contact details is all I need do to transfer the domain. This seems a bit simplistic to me, does this really constitute a full transfer?

Cheers

Rob

Comment: Not a programming question - try [sf] ?

Comment: Have just opened an account and copied it over to them, it's not really a server fault as such either though. It's dynamic framework management and integration, at an international level. I'd hope there is someone on either of the groups well enough informed to answer to be honest.

Comment: Change of owneship is change of the registrant. Transfer is more typically used for changing registrars, which has no relationship with eligibility requirements. If your registrar is not able to wlk you through and reply to your questions it may be a good sign that you need to change it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer came from ServerFault, indirectly. There was some discussion and careful reading of the EurID release, and eventually I decided I was best asking the Gamekeeper to advise the moocher. I asked EurID if the changing of the WHOIS details was enough to satisfy them. Turns out, they are basically after a "responsible adult" in the EU legal jurisdiction. They don't have daily means to work out what account owns the domain right back to the ISP account. So as long as the Contact details registered on the nameservers are within the EU, and it's a genuine contact who is entitled to EU rights, they are happy and Brexit should not impact the domain, or it's renewal. They will consider the named individual to be the owner though.